# want to disable required filed validation on one filed in onepagecheckout

Tags: onepage-checkout, validation

we are using onpagecheckout for checkout, currently we have passport/id field as required on checkout page, even thought i deleted the client side validation , its still saying "ID Type is a required value.", is there any place that i should change the validation ?

Comment: Can you please place the code for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer

i can change the required fileds in admin panel customers -> attributes -> customer attributes

Thanks  saravanavelu